# Large chunk of no activity in Chrome DevTools' network tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Okay, I'm trying to detect a reason for a slow loading of a website page using network tab in chrome devtools. In my past experience there always were some large files or slow links to 3rd party sources, but now I'm in total confusion because for a large amount of time there is no downloads at all:
[screenshot of network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heQub.png)

What is also strange is than for a last second there is a file with a size less than 1 kilobyte and it's loading for half of a second, although it's not a main issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Performance panel instead. My guess is that your page is running a lot of JavaScript during the "large chunk of no activity".

Open the Performance panel and click **Reload**.

[image: Reload]

If you see a wall of yellow activity in the CPU chart, it means that your CPU was completely busy running JavaScript.

[image: CPU]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/speed/imgs/overview.png))</sub>

The Audits panel is the best tool in DevTools for learning how to improve your page load speed. It runs a bunch of tests on whatever page you've got open and gives you tips on how to speed up the page. Check out [Optimize Website Speed](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/speed/get-started/).